# Atomic OS/Core OS for large scale Mesos cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mesos, coreos

I’m in the process of planning a proof-of-concept setup of [Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/), [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/) (or maybe [Marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/) and/or [Aurora](http://aurora.apache.org/)) and [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). The idea is to provision a cluster in our datacenter as a Mesos cluster and use e.g. Kubernetes to orchestrate the Docker containers.

For Docker and Kubernetes there are atomic host OSes like [Project Atomic](http://www.projectatomic.io/) and [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/) that are immutable and atomically updated but is there anything similar for Mesos, i.e. an immutable, atomic and lightweight platform for running the Mesos slaves and masters on bare metal or in a VM?

I figure such a platform would be the best way to distribute Mesos across a cluster (especially if it’s a big cluster) and then the rest of the functionality provided by Kubernetes and Docker would run on top of Mesos. Thus there is no need to distribute e.g. Docker to each node; my impression is that it’s taken care of by the Mesos-Docker integration.

Any alternatives to distribute Mesos across a big cluster/data-center that doesn’t require manual or Puppet/Chef/Ansible provisioning would also be of interest.

Regards, Ola

Comment: You can run Mesos on Core OS.

Comment: @rukletsov: Thanks for your reply. The thing is that the articles I've found seems to discuss running Mesos inside a Docker container on CoreOS e..g. http://www.recorditblog.com/post/how-to-deploy-mesos-with-high-availability-on-coreos/ and it seems a bit backwards to me. Maybe you know of some other approach?

What I would like to achieve is a setup with a lightweight OS straight on the metal but I'll probably start with running it in virtual machines.The only thing installed on top of the core OS is the Mesos slave.

Comment: I completely understand your requirement. First off, you can run Mesos agent (aka slave) on CoreOS not in Docker container, there are tricks to do that : ). Second, actually running a Mesos agent in docker is not that bad, all necessary primitives for handling starting and reconciling docker tasks have been already added to Mesos.

Comment: @rukletsov Interesting, the idea of Mesos inside Docker is interesting but I've read that there are technical difficulties (Mesos using some kernel level functions) related to that that makes it unsuitable for a production environment but maybe they are solved. I obviously need to look into CoreOS a bit more, my focus has so far been mostly on Project Atomic and its spin-offs.

Comment: You're right, there were technical difficulties with docker container reconciliation, but they were recently mitigated with the introduction of the Docker Executor. I would encourage you to try that out! Unfortunately, I can't say anything about Project Atomic, but it would be great if you try that out and report your experience on the Mesos userlist.

Comment: @rukletsov Thanks, I certainly will look into the Docker Executer and keep a close eye on Project Atomic. But still, it seems a bit akward to me to basically layer the execution as: CoreOS -> Docker -> Mesos Agent -> Docker which I guess would be the net effect since I would like to run my application containers on top of Mesos?

Comment: The chain is correct and I agree with you it seems a bit strange. On a second thought, since your app (last Docker in your chain) is started under a separate cgroups hierarchy, it doesn't really matter whether Mesos Agent is run in Docker or not. The only caveat is that it should be able co regain control over the dockers that were launched by the previous instance of the agent (which should be solved by DockerExecutor).